# I am solving the issues but I have got error that trying to get property 'user_role' of non object

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a code default built-in Auth **LoginController@login** The **login** function is override also I have a **users** table. Basically, I'm creating Panels(Admin, Staff) from a single login page. When **user_role** admin exists then open an **admin** page otherwise don't **log-in** the page. same as a **staff** page.

Comment: Admin exists means `users` table at least one user has an `admin` role? Am I right?

Comment: yes, I have entered dummy records for users table.

Comment: What is the field name for the user role? Please show your controller code so I will solve your problem.

Comment: Here I have LoginController@login

Comment: protected function login()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->user_role == 'admin')
        {
            return 'index/admin';
        }
        elseif (Auth::user()->user_role == 'staff')
        {
            return 'index/staff';
        }
        elseif (Auth::user()->user_role == 'student')
        {
            return 'index/student';
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
    }

Comment: Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('user_name')->unique();
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('user_role')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your <strike>login</strike> *redirect* page:

```
@auth
    @if(\Auth::user()->user_role == 'admin')
      //admin panel
    @elseif(\Auth::user()->user_role == 'staff')
     //staff panel
    @endif
@endauth
```

You don't need to change anything in your **LoginController** cause it's already handled by **middleware('auth')**.This will hide components that doesn't belong to the current user and user cannot log if not registered.

Comment: actually, I don't know auth code where we need to paste the auth code? I have created many pages. login-page, student, staff, admin page.

Comment: I thought you are just making a panel for each user role and view their respective data after login. So you have to redirect each user role to their respective page. You have to use the Model approach and use Relationships. You need to have a separate table for each user role and this will make it more complex. My approach was simple cause you only need to add a column in the users table.

Comment: ` Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin',function (){
        return view('admin');
    });
    Route::get('/student',function (){
        return view('student');
    });
    Route::get('/staff',function (){
        return view('staff');
    });
}); `

Comment: The most Laravel way to approach this is using Model and Relationships method. Try my approach above just add a condition for each user role or you can try Amit's answer but there's a problem in his approach. Other user role can access the other user role's page after login cause there's no more checking of the user role.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having "trying to get property 'user_role' of non object" on this code

```
Auth::user()->user_role
```

It basically means that your user isn't logged in and thus, `Auth::user()` returns null, try to `dd(Auth::user())` to verify this.

If that's the case, you will have to dig deeper on this lead.

Answer (score 0):

`In LoginController.php` file

**Remove**

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

**Add**

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; /*Add facade above controller class name*/

public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->user_role; 

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'admin':
            return 'index/admin';
        break;
        case 'staff':
            return 'index/staff';
        break; 
        case 'student':
            return 'index/student';
        break; 
        default:
            return '/home'; 
        break;
     }
}
```